# How to fix the "google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('No access token in response." when trying to open a spreadsheet using GoogleSheet API

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, gspread

I followed the video from TechWithTim step by step (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnPlKLEGR7E)
but I am still getting an error when I try to open the sheet.
The code works fine until `sheet = client.open("GuildTaxes").sheet1` line.
Here is my code.

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sprea...",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive...","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("GuildTaxes-9ba4508be840.json", scope)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

sheet = client.open("GuildTaxes").sheet1

data = sheet.get_all_records()

print(data)
```

Comment: In your case, when the Spreadsheet ID is used like `sheet = client.open_by_key("###")` instead of `client.open("GuildTaxes")`, what result will you retrieve?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer! After 2 hours, the scope in TechWithTim's video doesn't work for me, so if you stumble upon the same issue try using this one

```
scope = [
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
```

It is the default scope.